# Pass by reference and passing without reference in function

Tags: c++, reference, backtracking

i was solving this problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations-ii/

here is my working solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
vector<vector<int>> output;
void swap(vector<int>& nums, int index, int i){
    int temp=nums[index];
    nums[index]=nums[i];
    nums[i]=temp;
    return;
}
void helper(vector<int> nums, int index){ //here it is normally passed
    if(index==nums.size()){
        output.push_back(nums);
        return;
    }
    for(int i=index; i<nums.size(); i++){
        if(i!=index && nums[i]==nums[index]){continue;}
        swap(nums, i, index);
        helper(nums, index+1);
        // swap(nums, i, index);         //commented and used only with passed by reference
    }
}
vector<vector<int>> permuteUnique(vector<int>& nums) {
    int size = nums.size();
    sort(begin(nums) ,end(nums));
    helper(nums, 0);
    return output;
}
};
```

[WORKING example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OIhP.png)

and then this is the solution in which i am passing by reference and swapping while backtracking:

```
class Solution {
public:
vector<vector<int>> output;
void swap(vector<int>& nums, int index, int i){
    int temp=nums[index];
    nums[index]=nums[i];
    nums[i]=temp;
    return;
}
void helper(vector<int> &nums, int index){ //here nums is passed by reference
    if(index==nums.size()){
        output.push_back(nums);
        return;
    }
    for(int i=index; i<nums.size(); i++){
        if(i!=index && nums[i]==nums[index]){continue;}
        swap(nums, i, index);
        helper(nums, index+1);
        swap(nums, i, index);             //backtrack
    }
}
vector<vector<int>> permuteUnique(vector<int>& nums) {
    int size = nums.size();
    sort(begin(nums) ,end(nums));
    helper(nums, 0);
    return output;
}
};
```

[NOT WORKING Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jbju.png)

But this solution does not apppear to be working fine.
Can anyone please explain why there is a difference between the two?

Comment: Please don't expect us to interpret what "working fine" means.  Provide actual test data that you've used to determine "not working fine", and show what the output is, then show what output you expect.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about this feature. Now respective images have been added.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) reads: *DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.*

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when the helper function is called, nums vector must not change, i.e. in the for loop, nums must be the same for all iterations. When you pass nums by reference, helper function modifies it and it will be different for each iteration of the for loop. And the second swap is probably for recovering the original nums but it does not happen because you swap two indices, make some changes to the vector and you swap the exact indices back. It does not result in the original vector.